Seventies or Eighties EasternMysticism or Martial Arts SF Duology
I used to own the first book of what I think was a duology. I'm pretty sure I bought it, in England, in the late seventies, possibly early eighties, and it was recent at that time, so not a reprint of an old book.
I think the title of each book was a single word, or name, possibly Japanese.
Most likely the book was an imported US edition, possibly Ace.
As I remember, the cover showed a typically clean-cut, handsome young man, in clothes resembling a Karate Gi, or the clothes Luke Skywalker wore in 'A New Hope'. Most memorably I recall he was floating in space in the lotus meditating position, possibly with spaceships in the background. I'm not sure I even finished the book, but IIRC it was a conflict SF story, similar to Star Wars, in fact. Maybe a cash-in on the popularity at the time. Edit: Also 95% sure it was not by a "big-name" author - so not Niven, Haldeman, Brin, etc

Gah. I know these books. 80s. Cover is the same. One word title. Let me think...

Found it! The "Kensho" series by Dennis Schmidt. Actually five books, three with single-word titles. First on was Wayfarer. Found by viewing all Ace covers for 1979, on ISFDB.


Hi Bruno.  Please make sure you merge your accounts so you can regain control of your question and accept this answer.

The question and answer are the same account.

The question was posted by user #174328, and the answer by user #174329; just because the names are the same doesn't make them the same.

Well, I used the same email and the same password. Anyway. It's answered. You can delete the whole thing if you want. I'm done here.

Book mentioned at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54600/what-book-had-a-japanese-title-a-futuristic-samurai-head-on-the-cover-and-spel/54960#54960, although they're actually looking for another work by the author.
